# first is not a function while writing Jasmine test cases using angular 2-4

Tags: angular, redux, jasmine, jestjs

I am facing error while writing test cases with jasmine
[image]

I am writing test case for below code

```
 @select([
    'reportingTabState',
    'actualDelayDetails',
    'ActualDelayDetailsResponse',
    'DelayDetails',
    'actualDelayDetails',
  ])
  actualDelayDetails$;

this.actualDelayDetailsSub = this.actualDelayDetails$
      .first()
      .subscribe(actualDelayDetails => {
//rest of the code..
});
```

Mocking it in my spec.ts like this

```
const actualDelay$ = MockNgRedux.getSelectorStub([
            'ActualDelayDetailsResponse',
        ]);
        actualDelay$.next(actualDelayDetails);
        actualDelay$.complete();
        Object.defineProperty(component, 'actualDelayDetails$', { writable: true });
        component.actualDelayDetails$ = actualDelay$;

        fixture.detectChanges();
```

In actualDelayDetails I am having mock object like this:

```
const actualDelayDetails = {
    ActualDelayDetailsResponse: [{
        primaryDelay: {
            code: 'CR2F',
            minutes: '1 min',
            details: 'REPLACEMENT OF A FLIGHT OPS CREWMEMBER D',
            detailsDesc: 'REPLACEMENT OF A FLIGHT OPS CREWMEMBER D',
        },
        secondaryDelay: {
            code: 'F06',
            minutes: '23 min',
            details: 'DUE TO CAPTAIN DISCRETION TO NOT ACCEPT',
            detailsDesc: 'DUE TO CAPTAIN DISCRETION TO NOT ACCEPT',
        },
    }],
};
```

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'` (or something similar) inside your `main.ts`. This will patch the observable used inside your application to include this operator for chaining. You can solve this by including it on top of your test script, or in a global script which is loaded by your test environment.

Even better would be to move to the new way of chaining operators by using `pipe()`:

```
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.actualDelayDetails$.pipe(
  first()
).subscribe(() => {
```

This way you can be sure that what's used in your file, is also available in your tests

read more [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Answer (score 0):

"The first() operator takes an optional predicate function and emits an error notification when no value matched when the source completed."
So I tried removing first() method and it worked fine without breaking my functionality.
Thanks PierreDuc for instant reply. but unfortunately this solution was not working for me.